# NSDataDetector failing to detect invalid phone numbers

Tags: ios

I'm trying to use NSDataDetector to validate a phone number.  It doesn't seem to be working, which probably means I'm using it wrong but I can't figure out how.  All of these phone numbers in the code below should fail, the first for being all zeros and the rest for having too many digits in one of the sections.  Yet they are all passing validation.  I'm not 100% sure whether it's supposed to validate the content of the string, so the first one passing might be acceptable, but the rest are definitely not. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSArray *phoneNumbers = @[@"000-000-0000", @"1234-567-8901", @"123-4567-8901", @"123-456-78901"];
    for (NSString *phoneNumber in phoneNumbers)
    {
        if ([self phoneNumberIsValid:phoneNumber])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@ is valid", phoneNumber);
        } else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@ is not valid", phoneNumber);
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)phoneNumberIsValid:(NSString *)phoneNumber
{
    BOOL returnValue = NO;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDataDetector *dataDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:&error];
    NSRange phoneRange = NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length]);
    NSArray *matches = [dataDetector matchesInString:phoneNumber options:0 range:phoneRange];

    if (!error && [matches count] > 0)
    {
        NSTextCheckingResult *result = (NSTextCheckingResult *)[matches firstObject];
        NSLog(@"found number: %@", result.phoneNumber);
        if ([result resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber && NSEqualRanges(result.range, phoneRange)) {
            returnValue = YES;
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Output:

2014-07-11 10:27:15.520 PhoneValidationTest[90146:60b] found number: 000-000-0000
2014-07-11 10:27:15.522 PhoneValidationTest[90146:60b] 000-000-0000 is valid
2014-07-11 10:27:15.540 PhoneValidationTest[90146:60b] found number: 1234-567-8901
2014-07-11 10:27:15.540 PhoneValidationTest[90146:60b] 1234-567-8901 is valid
2014-07-11 10:27:15.542 PhoneValidationTest[90146:60b] found number: 123-4567-8901
2014-07-11 10:27:15.542 PhoneValidationTest[90146:60b] 123-4567-8901 is valid
2014-07-11 10:27:15.544 PhoneValidationTest[90146:60b] found number: 123-456-78901
2014-07-11 10:27:15.544 PhoneValidationTest[90146:60b] 123-456-78901 is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are assuming behavior `NSDataDetector` does not provide.

`NSDataDetector` does not require that possible phone numbers conform to a specific format so it will detect numbers with many lengths and variations of visual separators like `-` since those  do not impact the number dialed.

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers for some of the many ways phone numbers are currently in use. I think you'll find that all of your examples are valid in at least one region. They would also all conform to the phone number section of a `tel:` url as per [rfc2806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt).

`NSDataDetector` detects strings which might be phone numbers. If you want to enforce a specific format (hopefully knowing that you are eliminating valid numbers in the process) you'll have to further filter those results yourself.

Comment: If that's the case then the feature is basically useless.  I assumed it would look for phone numbers that match the format used in the device's location or default language or something along those lines.

Comment: I can see why you might expect that but those are not the only numbers a user might want to call. Consider international calls or any user travelling to a different locale and wanting to make a local call without needing to change their device settings. If you are confident that you can predict your users' needs and do not need to support most phone numbers then consider providing your own more restrictive expression to `NSRegularExpression`.